# Is there a way to make Microsoft Office Communicator / Lync save conversation histories more frequently?

Tags: ms-office-communicator, lync-2013

Autosaving conversation histories is enabled on the PCs at my company, but the autosaving seems to occur irregularly and infrequently. I'll randomly see a message about "this conversation" being saved, up to twice maybe thrice a day, but I don't know what triggers it, and sometimes when I seek a conversation from the day before in Outlook, I'm disappointed to find only the morning's conversations were saved.

Is there any way I can make Lync 2013 (but I had the same issues with MOC 2010) save conversations more frequently? (Or, is there at least a shortcut key that I can use to save all open conversations?)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ctrl+S before closing a window to save the conversation immediately.  I think you have to do this separately for each conversation, even if you're in a tabbed window.